# How to group together the items matching a specific condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through an array and displaying the search results if the result is either a "place" or "address". Here is the current output -

[image]

How to group all the items matching the first condition and all the items matching the second conditions like this -

[image]

Can anyone please help. Below is my code. Places should display first and next addresses

```
predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
        if(prediction.types.indexOf("postal_code")){
            console.log(prediction.types)
      results_html.push(`<h3>Places</h3><li class="autocomplete-item" data-type="place" data-place-id=${prediction.place_id}><span class="autocomplete-icon icon-localities"></span>                   
        <span class="autocomplete-text">${prediction.description}</span></li>`);

      }else if(prediction.types.indexOf("address")){
            console.log(prediction.types)
      results_html.push(`<h3>Address</h3><li class="autocomplete-item" data-type="place" data-place-id=${prediction.place_id}><span class="autocomplete-icon icon-localities"></span>                   
        <span class="autocomplete-text">${prediction.description}</span></li>`);

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Push them to separate arrays and then combine them later:

```js
results_places = [];
results_addresses = [];

predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
  if (prediction.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
    console.log(prediction.types)
    results_places.push(`<li class="autocomplete-item" data-type="place" data-place-id=${prediction.place_id}><span class="autocomplete-icon icon-localities"></span>                   
        <span class="autocomplete-text">${prediction.description}</span></li>`);

  } else if (prediction.types.indexOf("address")) {
    console.log(prediction.types)
    results_addresses.push(`<li class="autocomplete-item" data-type="place" data-place-id=${prediction.place_id}><span class="autocomplete-icon icon-localities"></span>                   
        <span class="autocomplete-text">${prediction.description}</span></li>`);

  }
});

if (results_places.length) results_places.shift('<h3>Places</h3>');
if (results_addresses.length) results_addresses.shift('<h3>Address</h3>');

results_html = results_places.concat(results_addresses)
```

Comment: `<h3>` and `<li>` can not be siblings

Comment: I'm guessing he probably has some code to handle that, or his original code would be broken

Comment: Thanks for helping this did answer the question that I posted. But the what if one of the conditions is not met. In that case, even if there are no results, the heading sill show up. I do not want to show the headings if there are no results. Could you please help

Comment: Just have to add a condition for when the array is empty